# Retopology Clothing After Knife Project

Tags: cloth-simulation, retopology

I'm working on modeling some clothing in Blender using the SimplyCloth plugin. To actually create the mesh itself, I'm using the technique of starting with a 100cm x 100cm plane, subdividing it into a 100x100 grid so I can get my measurements, and UV mapping it and applying a fabric material so I can make it look like each pieces were cut from one original piece of cloth.

I've used this technique before on a simple loose-fitting shirt made entirely of square pieces, which works quite well. However, I'm now making something that has a more complex, fitted shape.

I created a pattern to the correct shape, and then used Knife Project against my grid to "cut out" the pieces of fabric. This is the resulting topology:

[image]

Obviously I have issues now with triangles and N-Gons that will need to be cleaned up for good topology. Subdividing (so each grid is .5cm instead of 1cm) would held in some places, but not all. Any recommendations for how to proceed with this before I start trying to sew everything together?

Comment: The more important issue is not topology for your render-- quads, etc-- but topology for your cloth physics, which will bend only along your edges.  If you've been happy so far with your results, I don't expect you'll be any less happy with this, with or without ngon edges.  But, if you're concerned, the quickest way to retopo this will be a decent remesher.  Exoside Quad Remesher costs (like fifty bucks I think) but it will handle this task just fine and all you have to do is hit one button.  Not sure how Instamesh, free but second best IMO, will handle it.

Comment: Ideally these will become assets in a game, so it will be important beyond just the physics.

Comment: Then you'll want to retopologize *after* the physics.  Good topology follows the lines of the shape.

Comment: Then I'll need a way to retopologize while preserving the UV maps. The built-in Remesh modifier destroys the maps in the process. Retopologizing and UV mapping after the physics will throw all of that off.

Comment: There is no such thing as retopologizing while preserving UV maps, regardless of when you do it.  If you want good topo from bad topo, you won't be preserving UV maps, it's one or the other.  But for these simple, undistorted, unseamed cuts of planes, data transferring UV from a pre-retopo copy should be fine.

Comment: Yes, but won't retopo change the number of vertices? UV data can't be transferred if the geometry changes.

Comment: Transfer from nearest face interpolated.  Using a data transfer modifier.

Comment: Ok, that got the mapping. Between Black Fox and your comments I think I have a way forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit, my old answer didn't work, here is my revised method:

Add a solidify modifier to your plane to give it some thickness,
Add a remesh modifier *after* the solidify modifier. I'm using "Sharp" with the settings you can see below. This prevents N-gons and gives you a starting point.

[image]
[image]
[image]

If you need more resolution for the final product I'd recommend getting the topology correct on the lowest resolution version of your mesh that you can while maintaining the shape. Then, add in subdivisions as needed to get enough detail for your cloth.

You can also try deleting the central faces and doing a "grid fill" after applying the modifiers. This gives you a topology that might flow better for cloth simulation.

[image]

Comment: This fixes the topology, though I'll have to redo the UV maps. I'm hoping to find a solution that preserves them to retain the "cut from the same piece of fabric" look I'm trying to accomplish.

It also begs the question of maintaining the same face counts and edge lengths so they can sew properly.

Comment: You can use an object for UV projection to set up a map that won’t change as you change the topology. You can see here at around the 6:13 mark how to accomplish it. https://youtu.be/8NYNiayHvJI?si=QgXt9uYZq9WWu2OY

Comment: That doesn't preserve the existing UV map. It's just another method of baking the texture to a low-poly object, and not what I'm doing.